# Is there any way to automatically handle dependency injection when testing with Angular 6?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm pretty new to unit tests, Karma, Jasmine etc and I don't really know what I'm doing. I have run `ng test` and I got a tonne of test failures from the auto-generated tests that angular creates. It turns out 99% of these are just missing dependencies in the test scripts.

What I can't get my head around is why I need to sit here and look at every single component in my app and re-add the dependencies just so I can get a clean slate to start learning about testing. Is there no way for Angular to add all the dependencies I need to pass the auto-generated unit tests?

Comment: Maybe you can have a test module or modules where you can add providers needed by the tests. So next time you only need to add a dependencies in the module not in all the unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have a couple of choices here.

You can either mock all first-level dependencies, or you can use `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` to ignore child components.  `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` is dangerous though. And you'll still have to mock the services.

There are some npm packages that could help, like Spectator.  Here is my writeup on why you should mock, and how Spectator can help.

https://medium.com/@fivedicephoto/why-you-shouldnt-use-no-errors-schema-in-angular-unit-tests-cdd478c30782

But, for Angular to render a component, even for a test, it needs to satisfy the dependencies of the component.  So, no, there isn't a true "way around it".  But there are ways to remove the boilerplate of it all and simplify it.

I don't have any affiliation with Spectator.

[Edit]
Mocking is providing a fake object that satisfies the contract of a real one.  You can mock child components and services by satisfying their contracts.  However, if you have a lot of dependencies, as is common with a a container component, this can be burdensome too.

Comment: I'll be honest I have no idea what 'mock all first-level dependencies' means but ill try to figure it out. I thought there might be a library out there that would help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you actually import the REAL dependencies (child components, services in the constructor) then you have to import THEIR dependencies too.  That can be a rabbit hole.  What you need to do is create mock classes that satisfy the contract for the immediate children of the component.  You can use Jasmine spies to accomplish a lot of this in a very simple way. But it's more than I can give you guidance on in an answer like this.